# Error using ConvexHull from scipy

Tags: python, scipy, debian

I'm running a Debian based OS, on which I have python installed. I installed scipy using apt-get, however when I try to use the ConvexHull function from scipy.spatial, though scipy.spatial is imported the function is not recognized.

Comment: `from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull`?

Comment: `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` was added in scipy version 0.12.0.  Which version does debian provide? (You can check with `import scipy; print scipy.__version__`.)

Comment: It looks like Debian provides 0.10, very strange! Thanks anyways, I'll try and get the newest version

Comment: this is nonsense; Debian/wheezy provides scipy-0.10, but Debian/testing provices scipy-0.12

Comment: @Warren, It seems that's the correct answer, perhaps you should post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` was added in scipy version 0.12.0.  The current Debian/stable (aka wheezy) provides 0.10.1, and Debian/testing (aka jessie) has 0.12.0. (See, for example, http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-scipy.)